# How to retrieve data from a System.Object property in model during POST action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a model which contains an `object` property that can either be an `int`, a `string` or a `MyClass` object (which contains 3-4 properties) in runtime. Here is the general idea of my model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    // Can be int, string, or MyClass during runtime.
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the general idea of MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // These are correctly displayed in the EditorFor template.
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I have an `EditorFor(m => m.Value)` that correctly selects a template based on its runtime type.

During POST, the data from the view is correctly bound to the model and sent back to the controller as a parameter, but only if it's a `string` or an `int`. In fact, when `Value` is a `MyClass` object, it seems to be completely empty as if it came right out of a "`= new Object();`" statement. I cannot inspect it, as seen below:

[image: Inspecting Value]

I suspect this behavior is because on POST, the `Value` object is recreated using an empty constructor without having its runtime type specified, so when the binding happens, the properties don't match with a plain `System.Object` object.

If this is the case, how can I specify the object's runtime type during its re-creation? If not, how can I fix this binding issue?

Extra info: The `MyClass` properties are accessible through `Request` during controller POST (for example, `Request["MyModel.Quantity"]` would return the proper int value from the view). They just can't seem to get in the model.

Edit: As requested, here is what my view looks like:

```
@model MyModel

<div class="section">
    <div class="editor">
        <div class="editor-title">The Value field</div>
        <div class="editor-container">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Value)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would post a comment but I don't have enough reputation. Do you get more debugging information if you add a watch for `(dynamic) Value` instead of just `Value`?

Comment: Could you show us your view code?

Comment: Absolutely, I just edited the question with it.

Comment: The default model binder cannot do this. You could try with `public dynamic Value { get; set; }` but I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: Why not use separate properties for each possible data type?

Comment: How did you declare `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Value)` type is string or int?

Comment: @Alejandro The idea behind this is that in the future, `Value` could become more types like MyClass, so I thought going this way would reduce redundant coding. I could be wrong, and I will find another way if there is no solution to this issue. @D-Shih I do not understand the question. `m.Value` is an `object` type. It can change to int, string or MyClass at runtime.

Comment: @Sim I mean How did you know this value is string or int

Comment: @D-Shih In the controller GET method, I set Value's type to 1 of the 3 possible types mentioned above (using their `default` value, so 0 for `int`, `String.Empty` for `string` and `new MyClass()` for `MyClass`). If I put a breakpoint on the `EditorFor` line, I can clearly see without problem what the current type of `Value` is. This is not the case during POST when it's `MyClass`, but it works for `int` and `string`.

Comment: As I said, that's because the model binder can work with primitives just fine, but it cannot magically guess that 3 properties represent one of your classes. With `dynamic`, the JSON serializer should be able to create an anonymous type with the properties, though it won't be an instance of MyClass

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I forgot to answer you, sorry. I did try to change `Value`'s compile type to `dynamic`, but alas it still shows `{object}` in the inspector without its data. I'm starting to think this might not be what I should do.

Comment: How does the request data look like when you do the POST? (you can use the network tab of your browser to see that). I'm specially interested in the field names

Comment: I would attach a screenshot if not for the sensible data, but it basically looks like this (when Value is MyClass):
------WebKitFormBoundarysomecode
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ListMyModel[0].Value.Quantity"
0
-----WebKitFormBoundarysomecode
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ListMyModel[0].Value.Name"
TheName
-----WebKitFormBoundarysomecode
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ListMyModel[0].Value.IsAvailable"
True
The model is basically in a list, of a parent model, hence the `[0]`

Comment: Ah, so the list is most likely why the serializer doesn't kick in. I think you will need to have a property for each type you need to support

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I understand this is not an ordinary task and will go this route instead. Thanks!